# Firestore Rules - Allow list only with orderBy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore structure:

```
reports/{reportId}: {
  ...
  createdAt: Timestamp
  updatedAt: Timestamp
}
```

In my Ionic (Angular) app, I fetch the results like so:

```
this.afs
  .collection('reports')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .limit(180)
```

In my rules, I write the following rule:

```
/reports/{reportId} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit && request.query.limit == 180
}
```

This rule will allow to list the data as long as there's a limitation of 180 documents. The question is, how do I enforce the query to order by `createdAt` as `desc`? According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query) there's `request.query.orderBy`, but there's no explanation of how to use it

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the documentation on this is essentially non-existent at the moment.

`request.query.orderBy` is a Map where the fields are the name of the keys whose values are being ordered, and the value of the map are "ASC" or "DESC".  So, your rule would look something like this:

```
/reports/{reportId} {
  allow list: if request.query.limit &&
                 request.query.limit == 180 &&
                 request.query.orderBy.createdAt == "DESC"
}
```

Please bear in mind that the current implementation of `request.query.orderBy` has a significant problem.  A query can contain mulitple orderBy clauses, and the order of them does matter greatly.  However, it is currently not possible to determine the order in security rules.  **Given this shortcoming, it's possible that `request.query.orderBy` could be removed or changed in the future.**